# Why IDXGIAdapter cannot cast to IDXGIFactory?

Tags: c++, interface, com, direct3d, dxgi

I understand that DirectX does not follow the COM standard. However, they look heck of a lot similar, hence my confusion.

For simplicity, I use the word 'COM' *very* loosely, and I omit all HRESULT handlings, so please bear with me.

### Correct code:

Consider the following code.

```
ComPtr<IDXGIDevice3>            g_pDXGIDevice = nullptr;
ComPtr<ID3D11Device>            g_pD3DDevice = nullptr;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>     g_pD3DDeviceContext = nullptr;

D3D11CreateDevice(..., &g_pD3DDevice, ..., &g_pD3DDeviceContext);
```

A 'COM' object is instantiated. Since it is not a *pure* COM object, the component is instantiated through the D3D11 function `D3D11CreateDevice()` instead of the generic COM function `coCreateInstance()`.

Upon success, the function returns 2 COM pointers: `g_pD3DDevice` and `g_pD3DDeviceContext`. This enables the client to interact and use methods with the COM server without the burden of the implementation details.

```
g_pD3DDevice.As(&g_pDXGIDevice);
```

Next, we `QueryInterface` the DXGI device from the device interface through the `As` method of the ComPtr class.

The return is a success since the DXGI-device interface and the device interface are provided by the same COM object.

Next, we create the swap chain with:

```
ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> m_adapter = nullptr;
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory> m_factory = nullptr;

g_pDXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&m_adapter);
m_adapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_factory));
m_factory->CreateSwapChain(...);
```

This comes from the official MSD doc and works.

### Incorrect code:

Now, before creating the swap chain, let's do the following.

```
m_adapter.As(&m_factory);
```

This returns `E_NOINTERFACE`. Here's my confusion.

- Why can't we `QueryInterface` from `IDXGIAdapter` to get `IDXGIFactory`?
- Aren't they interfaces of the same DLL, that is, `dxgi.dll`?
- Are they interfaces pertaining to the same component object?

From [MSD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nn-dxgi-idxgiobject) documentation, `IDXGIAdapter` and `IDXGIFactory` are derived from the same base-class interface `IDXGIObject`.

Can we safely assume that they are interfaces of the same COM object, and thus, **it is possible to [navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/queryinterface--navigating-in-an-object) within the object interfaces** through `QueryInterface`?

If not, **how do we know** from the doc if two interfaces pertain to the same object? It seems that the doc is not clear about that.

To consolidate my arguments, in debug mode, we can clearly see that both `IDXGIAdapter` and `IDXGIFactory` come from the same DLL (see screenshot below).

[Screenshot of m_adapter and m_factory as items to watch in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rLps.png)

**So why does `m_adapter.As(&m_factory);` return an error?**

### Note

`IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain` has been deprecated since Direct3d 11.1 (see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgifactory-createswapchain)).

Comment: "IDXGIAdapter and IDXGIFactory are derived from the same base-class interface IDXGIObject, Can we safely assume that they are interfaces of the same COM object?" well, certainly not. Not all objects references "from the same dll" point to the same "object/implementation". This has nothing to do with packaging/dll. COM interfaces are abstract contracts implemented by you don't know who.

Comment: "COM interfaces are abstract contracts implemented by you don't know who." This is my problem. In the MS doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/), we have a list of all the interfaces, but we don't know to which object they pertain to. How would we know if these interfaces can dynamically cast (queryinterface) into each other? In the example of IDXGIAdapter and IDXGIFactory, how to determine from the doc if we can navigate within the object through QueryInterface? Why here we need to call "GetParent" instead of querying the interface directly?

Comment: What an object implement is in general documented, but indeed, it's not always obvious. In this case, you must call GetParent because that's how DXGI works per documentation: IDXGIAdapter and IDXGIFactory are just not the same object. Think about how they are implemented internally by Microsoft, they probably have defined a CAdapter and a CFactory C++ classes. CAdapter implements IDXGIAdapter, IDXGIAdapter2, IDXGIAdapter3, IDXGIAdapter4 and CFactory implements IDXGIFactory, IDXGIFactory2, ..., IDXGIFactory7.

Comment: Factory and apadters have one-to-many relationship. This fact alone suggests that you should not expect that those are castable one to the other.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Thanks for your reply. I think this answers my question.

Comment: @Roman R. Ok, got it. So two interfaces being part of the same DLL or derived from the same interface-base class does not guarantee that they are castable. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start is to read through [Microsoft Docs: Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).

In *many* cases the DirectX COM components allow you to do just what you say: If the C++ interface class inherits from another one, you should be able to `QueryInterface` up or down the chain with the same object instance. `IDXGIAdapter` is derived from `IDXGIObject`, so you can QI from the adapter instance to the object interface. `IDXGIFactory` is also derived from `IDXGIObject`, so you can QI to the object interface as well. Just because they both implement the same base interface, however, does *not* mean you an go from an instance of adapter to an instance of the factory. I.e., they are not the same 'object'. This mirrors C++ rules for inheritance: You can freely cast an instance of a class to it's publicly inherited parent, but *can't* freely cast back down the hierarchy.

There are some cases in DXGI where you can "navigate back" via `IUnknown::QueryInterface` and `IDXGIObject::GetParent`. For example, the following code is a good, consistent way to "get back" to the DXGI factory from a Direct3D 11 device:

```
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory1> dxgiFactory;
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
    if (SUCCEEDED(device.As(&dxgiDevice)))
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> adapter;
        if (SUCCEEDED(dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&adapter)))
        {
            hr = adapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiFactory));
            if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

While this works in simple cases like the one above, general type shifting is often problematic and/or buggy. For example, with Direct3D 11 there were problems if you use the `DXGICreateFactory` method instead of `DXGICreateFactory1`, or if you mixed both in the same process.

As such, for **DirectX 12** these DXGI back-track conversions (such as the code above) are explicitly *not supported*. You are expected to create the DXGI factory directly and then create the Direct3D 12 device from the enumerated adapter and -not- try to go the other way.

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/).

Really the only time you are expected to use those DXGI interfaces beyond enumeration is for "surface sharing" scenarios. See [Microsoft Docs: DX11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis) and [DX12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/direct3d-12-with-direct3d-11--direct-2d-and-gdi). Everything else is really there only for internal implementation purposes, and is therefore subject to change or other undocumented behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, it's an excellent answer. I think Microsoft somehow enforces a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In principle, we could navigate in the object using QI. But there is an implicit rule that an adapter object is NOT a factory object. To do so, `GetAdapter` creates a **new** adapter object instance. Next, `GetParent` instantiates a **new** parent object and casts it to a factory object. So, under the hood, we have 3 object instances (device, adapter, and factory). To prevent from mixing factory with adapter interfaces, MS prohibits casting.